# Init/managing concurrent SSH connections

Tags: go, struct, ssh, connection

I've searched high and low and I'm not sure if I'm using the wrong keywords, but I can't get my head around this. I'm building an app that take in a list of hostnames and connects to these over SSH. It is intended to maintain these connections (and reconnect when disconnects occur). Periodically, my program will take instruction and execute commands to some/all of these hosts.

My issue at the moment is, knowing that you cannot initialise a variable and not use it, I must dynamically create variables for these SSH connections so I can monitor/manage them independently (read/write, reconnect when necessary, etc). With my limited knowledge of go and a tendency to accidentally over-complicate things, the best I've come up with so far is using a struct and appending for each connection and its parameters (hostname, username, password, SSH config details, logfile location, etc).

Currently my dodgy code looks something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "flag"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "time"
    "encoding/xml"
    "bufio"
    "net"
)

// SSH connection struct
type SSHConnections struct {
    Host string
    User string
    Password string
    CLILogfile string
    SSHConn ssh.Client
    SSHConfig ssh.ClientConfig
}

func main() {
    //parse list of addresses
    var ipaddr = []string{"a.b.c.d","e.f.g.h"} //hard-coded for now

    //build out SSHConnections struct

    for i := 0; i < len(ipaddr); i++ {
        tempsshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
            User:   "administrator",
            Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
                ssh.Password("Password!"),
            },
            HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(), 
        }
        tempsshConfig.Config.Ciphers = append(tempsshConfig.Config.Ciphers, "aes128-cbc")
        var newitem = SSHConnections{
            Host: ipaddr[i],
            User: "administrator",
            Password: "Password!",
            CLILogfile: ipaddr[1],
            SSHConn: ssh.Client,
            SSHConfig: *tempsshConfig,
        }

        SSHConnections = append(SSHConnections, newitem)
    }
```

With the above code I get compile errors:

```
type ssh.Client is not an expression
type SSHConnections is not an expression
```

After this there are also connection-specific parameters (logfile declaration, additional SSH parameters, the actual SSH connection procedure) I will need to manage, presumably in the same struct as the above. With the above being my current stumbling block, I'm quite clueless how to fix that let alone integrate the below single-connection code into the above.

```
//extra SSH parameters required before connecting
sshConfig.Config.Ciphers = append(sshConfig.Config.Ciphers, "aes128-cbc")
modes := ssh.TerminalModes{
    ssh.ECHO:          0,     // disable echoing
    ssh.TTY_OP_ISPEED: 14400, // input speed = 14.4kbaud
    ssh.TTY_OP_OSPEED: 14400, // output speed = 14.4kbaud
}

//prepare logfiles
f, ferr := os.OpenFile("outputfile.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
if ferr != nil {
    panic(ferr)
}
defer f.Close() 

//SSH connection procedure
connection, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", hostname+":22", sshConfig)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to dial: %s", err)
}
session, err := connection.NewSession()
handleError(err, true, "Failed to create session: %s")
sshOut, err := session.StdoutPipe()
handleError(err, true, "Unable to setup stdin for session: %v")
sshIn, err := session.StdinPipe()
handleError(err, true, "Unable to setup stdout for session: %v")
if err := session.RequestPty("xterm", 0, 200, modes); err != nil {
    session.Close()
    handleError(err, true, "request for pseudo terminal failed: %s")
}
if err := session.Shell(); err != nil {
    session.Close()
    handleError(err, true, "request for shell failed: %s")
}
```

There's a whole load of irrelevant code I've cut out to make my post clearer. I hope I've remotely succeeded in that.

I'm not even sure a struct is what I want, but the dynamism of receiving a variable number of hostnames, and the requirement to control them individually is key. Later, I may need to tear-down connections individually as well, so a structure where they can be manipulated is what I'm looking for.

Any help to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

------------- update below this line ---------------

After mu's post below and some googling, my code now looks like this (removed imports):

```
var connections []SSHConnections

// SSH connection struct
type SSHConnections struct {
    Host string
    User string
    Password string
    CLILogfilepath string
    CLILogfile *os.File
    SSHConn *ssh.Client
    Session *ssh.Session
    SSHOut  io.Reader
    SSHIn   io.WriteCloser
    SSHConfig *ssh.ClientConfig
    CLIReady string
    SSHConnErr error
    SessionErr  error
    SSHOutErr   error
    SSHInErr    error
    CLILogfileErr   error
    CommandQueue    chan string
}

func handleError(e error, fatal bool, customMessage ...string) {
    var errorMessage string
    if e != nil {
        if len(customMessage) > 0 {
            errorMessage = strings.Join(customMessage, " ")
        } else {
            errorMessage = "%s"
        }
        if fatal == true {
            log.Fatalf(errorMessage, e)
        } else {
            log.Print(errorMessage, e)
        }
    }
}
func writeToFile(f *os.File, err error, inputString string) {
    if _, err = f.WriteString(inputString); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }   
}

func connectionWorker(i int) {
    //this function is to monitor SSH connections and reconnect if/when they are terminated
    fmt.Println("goroutine for: "+connections[i].Host)
    for { //not sure if this is even necessary? yet to test
        select {
            case command := <-connections[i].CommandQueue:
                fmt.Printf("received %v from queue\n", command)
            default:
                time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
        }

    }
}

func main() {

    //parse list of addresses
    var ipaddr = []string{"host1","host2"}

    //build out SSHConnections struct
    for i := 0; i < len(ipaddr); i++ {
        tempsshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
            User:   "administrator",
            Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
                ssh.Password("Password!"),
            },
            HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
        }
        tempsshConfig.Config.Ciphers = append(tempsshConfig.Config.Ciphers, "aes128-cbc")
        var newitem = SSHConnections{
            Host: ipaddr[i],
            User: "administrator",
            Password: "Password!",
            CLILogfilepath: ipaddr[i],
            SSHConfig: tempsshConfig,
        }

        connections = append(connections, newitem)
    }

    modes := ssh.TerminalModes{
        ssh.ECHO:          0,     // disable echoing
        ssh.TTY_OP_ISPEED: 14400, // input speed = 14.4kbaud
        ssh.TTY_OP_OSPEED: 14400, // output speed = 14.4kbaud
    }

    //establish connections, check each for relevant 'admin:' readiness
    for i := 0; i < len(connections); i++ {
        connections[i].SSHConn, connections[i].SSHConnErr = ssh.Dial("tcp", connections[i].Host+":22", connections[i].SSHConfig)
        if connections[i].SSHConnErr != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed to dial: %s")
        } else {
            connections[i].Session, connections[i].SessionErr = connections[i].SSHConn.NewSession()
            handleError(connections[i].SessionErr, true, "Failed to create session: %s")
            connections[i].SSHOut, connections[i].SSHOutErr = connections[i].Session.StdoutPipe()
            handleError(connections[i].SSHOutErr, true, "Unable to setup stdin for session: %v")
            connections[i].SSHIn, connections[i].SSHInErr = connections[i].Session.StdinPipe()
            handleError(connections[i].SSHInErr, true, "Unable to setup stdout for session: %v")
            if err := connections[i].Session.RequestPty("xterm", 0, 200, modes); err != nil {
                connections[i].Session.Close()
                handleError(connections[i].SSHInErr, true, "request for pseudo terminal failed: %s")
            }
        }
        if err := connections[i].Session.Shell(); err != nil {
            connections[i].Session.Close()
            handleError(err, true, "request for shell failed: %s")
        }
        //initialise the buffered CommandQueue channel
        connections[i].CommandQueue = make(chan string, 1000)

        //prepare logfiles
        connections[i].CLILogfile, connections[i].CLILogfileErr = os.OpenFile(connections[i].CLILogfilepath+".txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
        if connections[i].CLILogfileErr != nil {
            panic(connections[i].CLILogfileErr)
        }
        defer connections[i].CLILogfile.Close()
        writeToFile(connections[i].CLILogfile, connections[i].CLILogfileErr, "testing output to file\r\n")

        //monitor/maintain connections, monitor work queue and execute
        go connectionWorker(i)
    }
}
```

The above is not pretty and not perfect by any stretch, and may also need some tweaking if someone were to copy/paste so please keep that in mind. I'm certain there are lots of bugs that I'll stumble upon with proper testing, but for now it works as intended. My original queries are all answered now, thanks!

Comment: That's a syntax error, and you've omitted the part of the error message that tells you the exact location of the error. Proofread the code at that spot.

Comment: Apologies @JimB for confusion. I've since solved my issues, will update OP for the potential benefit of others.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop looks like this:

```
for i := 0; i < len(ipaddr); i++ {
    // ...
    var newitem = SSHConnections{
        // ...
        SSHConn: ssh.Client,
        // ...
    }

    SSHConnections = append(SSHConnections, newitem)
}
```

When you're building `newitem`, you don't have an `ssh.Client` for `SSHConn` so you should leave it out (and thus use its zero value) rather than trying to use the `ssh.Client` type as an expression; that's your first error.

The second error is similar: you're using a type (`SSHConnections` in this case) where you really want to be using a slice:

```
SSHConnections = append(SSHConnections, newitem)
```

should be:

```
someSlice = append(someSlice, newitem)
```

That loop should look more like this:

```
var connections []SSHConnections
for i := 0; i < len(ipaddr); i++ {
    // ...
    var newitem = SSHConnections{
        // Everything that's there now except the SSHConn ...
    }
    connections = append(connections, newitem)    
}
```

or, since you know how big `connections` needs to be:

```
connections := make([]SSHConnections, len(ipaddr))
for i := 0; i < len(ipaddr); i++ {
    // ...
    var newitem = SSHConnections{
        // Everything that's there now except the SSHConn ...
    }
    connections[i] = newitem
}
```

Then later on you call `ssh.Dial` and `connection.NewClient` to get the `ssh.Client`s that would presumably end up in your `connections`.

Also, you're probably better off using pointers to `SSHConnections` for `SSHConn` and `SSConfig` since that's what the package's interface wants to work with.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, this is my first SO post. Your post has been very helpful so far. I'm having an issue with one line of code now, but I'm not sure how best to show all my new code without tearing up OP and still maintaining context. Basically `var connections[i].SSHConn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", connections[i].Host+":22", connections[i].SSHConfig)` is throwing "syntax error: unexpected ., expecting type". Thoughts?

Comment: `var` is used to declare a variable like `var c ssh.Client`, you can't combine it with a short assignment `:=` and you don't use `var` with an struct field (such as `connections[i].SSHConn`) since that's not a variable. You'd probably want to either build all the pieces in local variables and then put them in the struct when everything has worked out or do a `var err error` to declare your `err` variable and then say `connections[i].SSHConn, err = ...` and such.

Comment: thanks again. Not sure why I can't tag your name, it's not auto-filling for some reason. After your input and a lot of googling I've solved all my issues for now. Big thanks. Will update OP.

Comment: I get notified about all comments on my answers (just like you get notified about all comments on your question and answers to your question AFAIK), that's probably why you can't @-me.